# Border Bottom length in header and footer

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, header

I am working on this website [blog.scene.app](https://blog.scene.app). I want to decrease border bottom length in header and footer. Right now it is stretching from left side and right side. But I want it to be right below the word and should not go outside either from left side or right side.
I have tried this code for header:

```
ul#menu-1-30fa770.elementor-nav-menu li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

and for footer I have written this:

```
ul#menu-1-b51f92a.elementor-nav-menu li:hover, ul#menu-1-388657d.elementor-nav-menu li:hover, ul#menu-1-71135f8.elementor-nav-menu li:hover{
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Only issue is bottom border on hover both in header and footer is going outside from left and right of text and I want that it should not go outside and stay only under the word. I am new to this and couldn't find any solution to do the task. Your help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border-bottom` extends to left and right because of the `padding` it has.
I removed the padding and added left and right `margin` instead. And here is the result you should get with this code:

```
ul#menu-1-30fa770.elementor-nav-menu li a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin: 0 20px;
}
```

[image]